# What is the metric on the Fuchsian model?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, fuchsian-groups

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper half plane, and $\Gamma < SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ be a Fuchsian group. How is the distance between any two points $x, y \in \mathbb{H} / \Gamma$ in the Fuchsian model defined?

Comment: How do you define a distance function on a Riemannian manifold? In your case, the quotient is an orbifold, but did you try to use the same formula?

Comment: What is "the Fuchsian model". Almost certainly not research level, voting to close.